# Basic question on how to read files in a directory

Tags: bash

This is a beginner question:
I'm trying to write a .sh file to automatically rename files in a directory.

The file would look something like

```
for fileName in directory
do
    mv fileName "NewPrefix"+fileName
done
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write the 
`for fileName in directory` part.

I tried the following:

```
dir = '.'
for fileName in dir
```

This is working, but whenever I run this script, I get `dir: cannot access =: No such file or directory.`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- Bash variables are used with `$VAR`, note the `$` in front. If you omit the dollar sign, it is treated like a regular string.
- Bash filename globbing needs a wildcard (`*`, `?`, etc.). Your example of `.` would match the folder `.`, which is the current folder.
- Variables are set with `VAR=VALUE`. There is no space around the equals sign. `VALUE` must be quoted if it has spaces.
- String concatenation occurs automatically. The `+` sign inserts a literal `+` at that position.
- Variables should always be used surrounded with double quotes unless you have a reason not to.

With these points in mind, here is a working version of your script.

```
cd /path/to/folder

for file in ./*
do
    mv "$file" "NewPrefix$file"
done
```

---

#### If conditions

If conditions are used like so:

```
if [[ "$file" == "New"* ]]
then
    # Do something here
fi
```

Note that the asterisk is *outside* the double quotes.

Comment: I can't vote up because I don't have enough points but thanks a bunch!

Comment: will do (I need to wait five more minutes to accept an answer). I have one more question please: What if, instead of renaming my files "New..." I wanted to do the contrary (I have "New.." files I want to rename without the "New". I tried i(3:end) but it doesn't work...

Comment: @teaLeef Where are you getting these examples? They are not for bash. To answer your second question though, you need to do `mv "$file" "${file#???}"` as the `mv` line in my code. This will trim the first 3 characters from the file name.

Comment: Actually I had never written bash scripts before, so I'm trying to inspire from other programming languages. Thanks though!

Comment: @teaLeef Bash is more of a scripting language, so its syntax differs from languages like C or Python. If you're getting started, I might suggest this tutorial: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide for teaching you correct syntax and style.

Comment: thanks for the link. I have one last syntax question please: In my `for` loop, I would like to check whether the name of the file starts by "new". I'm trying to write something like `if $file == "new* ...` How can I do that?

Comment: It actually doesn't work , I get `[[ not found`...

Comment: @teaLeef I am not sure why that is so. Are you sure you're running your script with `/bin/bash` and not `sh`? It works for me

Comment: I used sh (I had read a post saying sh and bash were very close...). I tried adding `#bin/bash` at the brginning of my script and execute it using bash. This time, I don't have an error, but nothing is done actually...

Comment: @teaLeef You need `#!/bin/bash` at the start. Bash and sh are quite different. Bash is sh with more features, sh is more POSIX (standards) compliant

Comment: I corrected this. Then I tried to execute `bash file.sh` and `/bin/bash file.sh` but it still does nothing...

Comment: @teaLeef Are you sure? nothing is printed if it runs. Just make sure you `cd` to the folder you want to operate on then run the script. If you want it to print files moved, add the `-v` option to `mv`.